# Django websocket ValueError

Tags: django, websocket, channel

When I access a websocket on a non-existent put (ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/dgd/), django raises an error

Is this normal behavior or should I handle this case?

```
2021-10-04 11:35:46 ERROR    server Exception inside application: No route found for path 'ws/dgd/'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/934214/PycharmProjects/uhrg_2.0/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/934214/PycharmProjects/uhrg_2.0/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/934214/PycharmProjects/uhrg_2.0/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "/Users/934214/PycharmProjects/uhrg_2.0/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 263, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "/Users/934214/PycharmProjects/uhrg_2.0/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 185, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/934214/PycharmProjects/uhrg_2.0/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/934214/PycharmProjects/uhrg_2.0/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 168, in __call__
    raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/dgd/'.
```

routing.py

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/user/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/$', consumers.UserConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    },
}
```

asgi.py

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websockets.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: It's normal for a request that doesn't match a route to raise an error. Are you asking if the error should be handled better?

Comment: Yes, I tried to process for this example, but I still get the error
https://lambda.tw/blog/how-to-fix-no-route-found-error-on-django-channels/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your question is if the behavior of the websocket-library you're using is normal or whether your configuration is correct, so I'll try to cover both in my answer.

It is certainly normal and **important** for the library (channels) to raise an exception when a user tries to connect to a **url** which is not defined in  your routing. It might pollute your logging file(s) though when a user should try to connect to a non-existing url repeatedly, so you might want to **implement some handler** which logs this scenario in a more elegant way.

When you compare the url you defined in your **routing.py** and the url you're trying to call, you should realize straight away that the patterns do not match.